# How to use ff package in R on a remote machine?

Tags: database, r, bigdata, rstudio

I have been using ff package for writing and reading a huge dataset. This package allows me to read and write to tables on my local machine. I wish to have a dedicated machine for data collection which is a remote machine. I could not find anything in the package that lets me do this. Is there an easy way to achieve this? If not could you please suggest another R package that is efficient in handling big data and also portable on a network?

Comment: How about installing rstudio server on the remote machine?

Comment: Buy your machine somewhere, install R on it and RStudio if you like that user interface and install the ff package on it and off you go. I use that setup for several projects I'm working on. So what stops you from doing it?

Comment: I do not want both my R Session and my database server to be the same. The R Session needs to be mobile as we have a load sharing algorithm and if 1 machine is getting loaded up, the R Session is moved to another machine. Hence I can't have dependent files on that machine. I was thinking of having a dedicated machine for storage and the R session will access that for data. So even if it is moved, I am good to go.

Comment: I've found that building a package with the necessary functionality and then installing on the remote machine or cluster is a solution. Then you have a basic deploy (bash) script that loads the public and custom packages. I do this myself for database connectivity on a cluster.

Comment: Maybe use a shared drive to store your ff files? But not NFS.

Comment: From what you said it is not a database server but a file server that you want. You have only two options to use ff: either copy the file locally, modify it then copy it back to the server, or work on it using a network filesystem, but beware of concurrent writes on the file.

Answer (score 1):

last week Jared Lander (author of the book "R for Everyone") helped is in creating a R tint on a bigboards.io hex. We installed RStudio Server on it and we use the whole storage/processing capabilities of the hex. 
Ceph is used to distribute the data on the nodes

Anyway, it feels like a solution for your question.